# How to fix flickering drawings in PyGame? Only updating screen once

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.constants import MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, MOUSEBUTTONUP
import random

pg.init()
WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 700

screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen.fill("white")

boxIMG = pg.image.load('asteroid.png')

rndCorner = [(0, 0), (0, 700), (700, 0), (700, 700)]

def draw_screen():
    obstacle = pg.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), (random.choice(rndCorner)), (200, 200), 2)

def box(x, y):
    screen.blit(boxIMG, (x, y))

def game_loop():
    
    running = True
    left_clicking = False
    boxX = 0
    boxY = 0
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    
    while running:            
        screen.fill("white")
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
                pg.quit()
                
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    left_clicking = True
                    
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if event.button == 1:
                    left_clicking = False
                    
        if left_clicking:
            boxX, boxY = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            boxX -= 32.5
            boxY -= 32.5
            
            if boxX < 0:
                boxX = 0
            elif boxX > 635:
                boxX = 635
            elif boxY < 0:
                boxY =  0
            elif boxY > 635:
                boxY = 635
                
        # Update Screen
        draw_screen()
        box(boxX, boxY)
        pg.display.update()
        
        clock.tick(60)
                    
game_loop()
```

So I am running into an issue where the lines I drew when calling 'draw_Screen()` are flickering. I tried using doublebuf but that didn't fix the issue for me. If you are wondering what I am trying to achieve, I am trying to move the box (main player) while holding the left click button, hence the 'if left_clicking'

Comment: You are drawing random lines from the corner to the middle(ish) every frame, so 60 times a second, and then filling the screen with white and then drawing another, so no wonder they are flickering.  what are you trying to do with the lines from the corners?

Answer (score 1):

You choose a new random corner coordinate in every frame. This causes the flickering. Pick a random corner once and use the same coordinate in every frame:

```py
random_corner = random.choice(rndCorner)
def draw_screen():
    obstacle = pg.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), random_corner, (200, 200), 2)
```